# Can you hash an ssh key to generate a symmetric password?

Tags: hash

Let's say you need a 256 bit password but all you have is an SSH key.  Can you securely transform the SSH key into a symmetric password via a hashing function?  What would be a good choice for a hash function?

Comment: Ah SSH *public* key, or an SSH *private* key?

Comment: Assuming they're both secret material, does it matter which one?

Comment: A public key isn't secret material.

Comment: It is if you don't share it with anyone :)

Comment: What's the purpose of having an SSH keypair if you aren't going to put the public key on other machines to SSH to? And if you *are* putting the public key on other machines, should all of them really be able to access this password?

Comment: That's a different question, now isn't it :)

Comment: I'm asking because this sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: yeah, you have no idea.  :)  No worries though.   i actually am trying to re-purpose an ssh key into a symmetric password.

Comment: You said "you have no idea". This is offensive, and putting the blame on the wrong person. Your question does not contain the necessary information to answer it, it's *your job* to provide that information. It is not other people's task to guess what your intention is. However, you are proposing a solution and don't describe the actual problem. And that is what the *XY problem* stands for. Anyway, public information is public - that's a definition, not up for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... Assuming:

- That they were generated using enough entropy (probably yes if they were generated securely)
- That they are only used for this purpose (I'd guess you can hash private key, but then as soon as it is compromised, your key is too)
- It isn't done using public key, if that key is then published

As for hash function, any hash that isn't broken will do.

Comment: I'd recommend HKDF so you can assign a unique tag to it, and because it's explicitly designed for and has security proofs aimed at this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the question: What is a "256 bit password"?

The term *password* is usually used for low entropy, poorly chosen (mostly by a user) random value, in contrast to a  *(cryptographic) key*, where we assume it is drawn with high entropy from a uniform distribution (truely random), or alternatively created by a cryptographically secure pseudorandom functionality (for example a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_function), [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) or [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator). And none of those are the same).

And then it isn't exactly clear what you mean with "transform securely", because there is not a single definition of security, there are a lot of it. A hash function is one way of such a transform, and a proper hash function (state-of-the-art, with matching output length) does work as one-way function, with the usual properties of collision resistance and preimage resistance.

But actually, a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) is the concept you are looking for. One possible realization is password hashing, possibly with salts. Another one was noted in the comments by Stephen Touset already: [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF). There are also KDFs like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), which are designed for poorly chosen inputs (usually called "passwords"), which still give good results by scaling the computational effort for dictionary attacks up.

> What would be a good choice for a hash function?

If you want a suggestion for one explicit hash function, SHA-256 is most commonly suggested. In the future this might change, once the support of SHA-3 has become more common. Hash function can be building blocks for KDFs, but I would suggest to use an implementation of those directly.

And since you didn't answer in the comments if you want to use the private or public SSH key: If you use the public key, this is insecure by default, unless your key also depends on another password or cryptographic key. Just think of the public key as a random public value, and that an attacker knows the algorithm you are applying. Assuming otherwise would be wrong, see [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).